# Month filter to be defaulted to current month whenever user opens the report

Tags: date, filter, default, spotfire

I have a month column in the data and I am adding this as a filter so that user can filter whichever month he wants.

I want the month filter to be defaulted to current month whenever user opens the report and then he can change the month based on his needs. Is this possible in spotfire?

Answer (score 1):

You can create the calculated column with the following definition and pick current month as a filter.

```
If(Month([Date])=Month(DateTimeNow()),"Current month",String([Date]))
```